# c++ длинные синонимы через using

Tags: c++, классы, типы-данных

Подскажите, можно ли средствами C++ как-нибудь реализовать новый тип, состоящий из нескольких слов, как `long int`, что-то типа

```
using long data_t = CMyData<long int>;

long data_t value;
```

?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду добавить модификатор???

Comment: Так у вас тип и так состоит из трех слов - `CMyData`, `long`, `int` и еще скобоччки.

Answer (score 2):

Нельзя.

Сделайте `using long_data_t = ...;`.

Answer (score 0):

Создать такой же тип, с чрезмерным выравниванием:

```
using long_data =
struct alignas(sizeof(CMyData<long>) * 2) 
    D : public CMyData<long> {};
```

(если я вас правильно понел)